# Workflow instances deleted after 30 days

Tags: workflow, timer-jobs, cleanup

I have read about the Workflow Auto Cleanup timer job that is defaulted to clean up all cancelled and completed workflow instances after 60 days. I have also read that you are unable to disable this feature in SharePoint online.

When I click on a list item to see the workflow information, I get a screen that says.

> "We can't find the workflow. Completed instances are automatically
>   cleaned up after 30 days."

I've googled about this, but can only find the 60 day timer job.
Has anyone seen anything similar or have any resources regarding this?